# Import works in Pyscripter2.6 and Python26 Console, but not in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python-2.6, error, import

I'm trying to "import clr" and get an error saying "dynamic module not initialized properly". It works fine in Pyscripter and the regular console (which is actually updated from the PythonNet build), but I can't figure out why it won't work in the ArcMap Python window.

It's a module from PythonNet that I compiled from their source code (which had it's issues, but got it working this far). Where should I be looking next to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [my answer here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31272/391). Basically if you compiled it yourself, you're going to need to patch distutils to not embed a manifest in the DLL.